# React / Express / MySQL - Where to put MySQL transactions?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I am developing a React front + Express backend API using MySql.

I have some trouble figuring out where to do MySql transactions.

My Express API folder structure is like this :

- API

  - models/
  - controllers/
  - routes/
  - app.js

Models/ folder has files holding the skeletons of my MySql tables as classes, with the methods calling the DB as static methods. One of the file (Student.js) in the models/ folder looks like this :

```
// models/Student.js

const sql = require('./db'); // DB connection in this file

class Student {
    constructor(student) {
        this.id_student = student.id_student;
        this.name = student.name;
        this.surname = student.surname;
        this.email = student.email;
        this.current_year = student.current_year;
        this.id_section = student.id_section;
    }

    static getAllStudents(callback) {
        sql.query('SELECT * FROM student', (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(`Error : ${error}`);
                callback(null, error);
                return;
            }
            console.log(`Elèves : ${JSON.stringify(results)}`);
            callback(null, results);
        });
    };
}
```

In controllers/ folder, the student.js file would look like this :

```
// controllers/student.js

const Student = require('../models/Student');

exports.getAllStudents = (req, res) => {
    Student.getAllStudents((error, students) => {
        if (error) {
            res.status(400).send(`Error retriving students - getAllStudents from controller/student.js - : ${error}`);
        }
        else {
            res.status(200).json({ students });
        }
    })
};
```

In routes/ folder, I simply call the corresponding controller and use its methods depending on the route.

The point is, I have another file in my models/ folder (which look like models/Student.js) : Section.js

I need to do a transaction to insert values into the student table and the section table (which each are represented as separated files in models/ folder, as explained).

The question :

- Where should I make this transaction ? In which file from the models/ folder ? Student.js or Section.js ? Or another kind of file ? If so, in which folder and how so ?

Thank you very much for taking the time to help me

### ------ UPDATE ------

Here is a picture of the tables relations :

[Table relations](https://pasteboard.co/Jcvt9Dq.png)

As you can see, Student table has relations with Section (actually what I call the Section table is called section_relations table and is a "linking table").

When creating a Student, I first check, on the student table, if id_section_group and id_section_promo exist in section_relations tables.

If not, I want to first create the section (filing all the needed FK ids) then create the student. This should be in a transaction, inserting the FK ids to the section table to create the section then create the student.

This should be done in a transaction, as it can rollback if one of the 2 inserts fail.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the relationship between Student and Section, one thing is clear, the **Student** model should only do transactions on the **student** table and the **Section** model should only do transactions on the **section** table, then you will need to handle the logic of calling those transactions in the controller, which controller?, how I said, it depends on the relationship and what are you trying to achieve:

- if a student updates a section, then you should do it in the Student
  controller
- if a section updates the student, then use the Section controller
- if they don't have a relationship, then you handle each one in their
  respective controller.

Comment: The Student and Section tables have 3 relationships (actually 2 mores fields in the models/Student.js file are linked to the Section table). The thing I want to do is, when submitting a form creating a Student, if the student Section doesn't exist, create it then create the Student. This should be done in a transaction to not mess up my DB tables, as I would have the possibility to rollback. The question is, in which file should i make the transaction happen, in this case ? Thank you for your time

Comment: You should create the transaction in the student controller and call the section controller inside to make the other operations, the transaction is a promise, you can use `then` to commit and `catch` to rollback.

Comment: Do you mean make the transaction in the student model (as all my queries are in the models/ folder) then call the function from the student model to its controller ? As for the controllers, is it OK to call several different models in one controller ? Thank you very much (you can see the update and picture of the tables + relations in my post)